# Selenium PhantomJsDriver, C#, SendKeys not working properly

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When using the `ChromeDriver` and using `SendKeys("some text")` to fill in an `input field` it all works fine. When switching to the `PhantomJsDriver`, **only the last char of the string is contained in the element**. So `element.SendKeys("My text");` will result in that `element.GetAttribute("value")` becomes `"t"` and not `"My text"`.

Ideas on how to fix this?

//Daniel

Comment: What version of GhostDriver are you using?

Comment: The one part of the latest NuGet, http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/ and the latest version of PhantomJs for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load latest selenium web-driver nu-get package
2. Load latest PhantomJs browser
3. If this will not resolve your issue, you can create overloaded function that will execute javascript code that will do "sendKeys"